# Cifrado César que se convierte a ASCII

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy realizando una página *HTML* que usa *JavaScript*. Lo que hace es que introduce un texto y lo cifra con césar, y después lo convierte a *ASCII*.

El problema es que no puedo descifrar el texto ya cifrado.

```js
function Codifica(Descifra)
{
  var Desplazar = document.getElementById("cambios").value;
  if (!/^(\+|\-)?\d+$/.test(Desplazar)) {
    alert("No es un número entero");
    return;
  }
  var Des = parseInt(Desplazar, 10);
  if (Des < 0 || Des >= 26) {
    alert("El abecedario tiene 26 letras, te pasaste.");
    return;
  }
  if (Descifra)
    Des= (26 - Des) % 26;
  var textElem = document.getElementById("texto");
  textElem.value = Desplazo(textElem.value, Des);
}
function Desplazo(texto, Des) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) {
    var c = texto.charCodeAt(i);
    if (65 <= c && c <=  90)
      result += String.fromCharCode((c - 65 + Des) % 26 + 65).charCodeAt(0);  
    else if (97 <= c && c <= 122)
      result += String.fromCharCode((c - 97 + Des) % 26 + 97).charCodeAt(0);  
    else
      result += texto.charAt(i);  
  }
  return result;
}
```

```css
.ca {
  background-image: url("louis-vuitton.jpg");
}
.text{
  position:relative;
  top: 150px;
  left: 530px;
}
.kaik{
  position:relative;
  top: 200px;
  left: 850px;
}
.PE{
  position: relative;
  top:50px;
  left:700px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body class="ca">
    <form>
      <H1 CLASS="PE">CIFRADO</H1>
      <textarea  class="text" id="texto" cols="50" rows="10" style="width:40em; height:15em"></textarea>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input class="kaik" type="text" id="cambios" value="" style="width:4em;" />
      <input class="kaik" id="caik" type="button" value="Cifra" onclick="Codifica(false);" />
      <input class="kaik" id="caik" type="button" value="Decifra" onclick="Codifica(true);" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, visita el [tour] para que sepas como funciona esta comunidad. Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía: _[ask]_, recuerda que puedes formatear tu código para que sea legible con el botón `{ }`. Es importante que seas específico y concreto al describir tu problema, de otro modo tu pregunta podría ser cerrada.

Comment: Adicionalmente al comentario que ya hicieron; te sugiero en los **alert** coloques el mensaje que se informaria al usuario y que sea ilustrativo de lo que se valida para entender/seguir tu código mejor. Además `cambios` no veo en que momento es cambiado su valor.

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas si, los alert son de prueba. No, si cambia los valores. De texto ascii, osea cifrar. Lo que no puedo hacer es descifrar.

Comment: Cifrado Cesar JavaScript http://alexweb.eu/cesar
puedes ver el codigo en inspeccionar pagina

Answer (score 1):

antes de empezar con mi posible respuesta te diré que concuerdo con @toledano.

Te hice este pequeño ejemplo, espero y te sirva:

```js
var alfabeto = 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
    desplazamiento = 3,
    boton_de_cifrar = document.getElementById('cifrar'),
    boton_de_descifrar = document.getElementById('descifrar'),
    entrada = document.getElementById('input'),
    salida = document.getElementById('output');

    function cifrar(input, output, desplazamiento){
        var resultado = '';
        //Usaremos un bucle
        for(var i=0, c; c=input[i]; i++){
            var caracter_actual = '',
                indice_actual = alfabeto.indexOf( c );

            if((indice_actual + desplazamiento) <= alfabeto.length){
                //Desaplazamos el caracter.
                caracter_actual = alfabeto[ (indice_actual + desplazamiento) ];

                //Convertimos a ASCII
                caracter_actual = caracter_actual.charCodeAt( 0 );

                //El guion lo usamos para delimitar cada caracter cifrado y poder decifrarlo.
                resultado += caracter_actual + '-';
            }
            else{
                var indice_actual_temporal = indice_actual + desplazamiento,
                    sobrante = indice_actual_temporal - alfabeto.length;

                //
                //Usaremos solo el desplazamiento para reemplazar el caracter.
                caracter_actual = alfabeto[sobrante];

                //Convertimos a ASCII
                caracter_actual = caracter_actual.charCodeAt( 0 );

                resultado += caracter_actual + '-';
            }
        }

        output.value = resultado.replace(/\-$/, '');
    }

    function descifrar(output, desplazamiento){
        var array_de_caracteres = output.value.split('-'),
            resultado = '';

        //Usaremos un bucle
        for(var i=0, c; c=array_de_caracteres[i]; i++){

            c = String.fromCharCode( parseInt( c ) );

            var caracter_actual = '',
                indice_actual = alfabeto.indexOf( c );

            if((indice_actual - desplazamiento) >= 0){
                caracter_actual = alfabeto[ (indice_actual - desplazamiento) ];

                resultado += caracter_actual;
            }
            else{
                var indice_actual_temporal = indice_actual - desplazamiento,
                    sobrante = parseInt(indice_actual_temporal.toString().replace('-', '') );


                caracter_actual = alfabeto[alfabeto.length - sobrante];

                resultado += caracter_actual;
            }
        }

        output.value = resultado
    }


    boton_de_cifrar.addEventListener('click', function(){
        cifrar(entrada.value, salida, desplazamiento);
    }, false);

    boton_de_descifrar.addEventListener('click', function(){
        descifrar(salida, desplazamiento);
    }, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Texto a cifrar">
<button id="cifrar">Cifrar Texto</button>
<hr>
<input type="text" id="output" placeholder="Aqui aparecera el texto cifrado">
<button id="descifrar">Descifrar Texto</button>
```

Usé un solo caracteres alfanuméricos para el ejemplo, espero y te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando de cifrado de datos se trata, el método cesar es el menos recomendado por lo que en mi ejemplo utilizare el [cifrado Vigenère](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifrado_de_Vigen%C3%A8re), este consiste en cifrar un texto plano utilizando una clave de encriptación,

```js
function encrypt(){
 var
  data=document.getElementById("data").value,
  key=document.getElementById("key").value;

 var encrypted=crypt(data,key);
 document.getElementById("encrypted").value=encrypted;

 var encrypted=crypt(data,key);
 document.getElementById("encrypted_ASCII").value=HTA(encrypted);

 var decrypted=crypt(encrypted,key);
 document.getElementById("decrypted").value=decrypted;
}
function crypt(data,key) {
 var crypted="";
 for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++ ){
  crypted+=String.fromCharCode(data.charCodeAt(i)^key.charCodeAt(i%key.length));
 };
 return crypted;
}
function ATH(s) { // Convierte una cadena ASCII to HEX
  for (var ath="", i=0; i<s.length-1; i+=2) {
    ath += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(s.substr(i,2),16));
  }
  return ath;
}

function HTA(s) { // Convierte una cadena HEX a ASCII
  for (var hta="", i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
    var z = "0"+s.charCodeAt(i).toString(16).toUpperCase();
    hta += z.substr(z.length-2,2);
  }
  return hta;
}
```

```html
dato a encriptar:<br>
<input id="data"><br>
clave de encriptacion:<br>
<input id="key" onkeyup="encrypt()"><br>
<br>
dato encriptado:<br>
<input id="encrypted"><br>
dato encriptado (ASCII):<br>
<input id="encrypted_ASCII"><br>
dato des-encriptado:<br>
<input id="decrypted"><br>
```

Una vez que haz encriptado el dato puedes convertirlo a ascii utilizando las siguientes rutinas:

```js
function ATH(s) { // Convierte una cadena ASCII to HEX
  for (var ath="", i=0; i<s.length-1; i+=2) {
    ath += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(s.substr(i,2),16));
  }
  return ath;
}

function HTA(s) { // Convierte una cadena HEX a ASCII
  for (var hta="", i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
    var z = "0"+s.charCodeAt(i).toString(16).toUpperCase();
    hta += z.substr(z.length-2,2);
  }
  return hta;
}
```

Espero esto te ayude, Saludos!! ;))...